# $a_n = b_n -b_{n-1}$ Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ exists

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence
Let $a_n = b_n - b_{n-1}$.
Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ exists.

I am extremely stuck on this homework problem and have no clue where to start. Help is extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove? That $\sum_1^\infty(b_n-b_{n-1})$ converges iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exists?

Comment: That the summation of a_n as it approaches infinity converges if and only if the limit of b_n exists.

Comment: Again this question?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**. Observe that, by telescoping terms,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=\sum_{n=1}^N(b_n-b_{n-1})=b_N-b_0
$$ then let $N \to \infty$.